# How do I access command line arguments in SICStus Prolog?

Tags: prolog, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to create a `cmd` (batch) file that will compile and build a Prolog program using SICStus.

I have the `cmd` code here:

```
call "c:\Program Files (x86)\SICStus Prolog VC12 4.3.2\bin\sicstus.exe" -l build_program.pl
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat"
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\SICStus Prolog VC12 4.3.2\bin\spld.exe" --output="program.exe" --static "program.sav"
```

And the `build_program.pl` is:

```
:- set_prolog_flag(unknown, fail).
:- set_prolog_flag(redefine_warnings, off).

:- nl, nl, nl.

:- prolog_flag(argv, Args).
:- write(Args).
:- prolog:set_current_directory('source/program').
:- compile(program).

:- nl, nl, nl.

:- halt.
```

Now I know I can send arguments to SICStus using `-a` but I'm not sure what is the correct way to send them or to access them.

As you can see in `build_program.pl` I have tried ...

```
:- prolog_flag(argv, Args).
:- write(Args).
```

... but the output was `_282447` so I don't think I'm doing it the right way.

Comment: thanks !! that worked .. and how can i access the first value in this array ?

Comment: Sorry i thought that the flags is sicstus specific. . thank you .. Could you post it as an answer  ill mark it ..  Im kinda new in all this trying to figure out things as i go .. Thanks !!!

Comment: Why do you switch off warnings and very helpful error messages? (That's the first two lines)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the following?

```
:- current_prolog_flag(argv, Arguments), writeq(Arguments), nl.
```

Make sure you use the same variable twice in one clause! So far, you are having a scoping issue: you have two clauses using distinct variables having the same name.

If you want to access the first item of list `Args`, add an additional goal `Args = [A1|_]` like so:

```
:- current_prolog_flag(argv, Args), Args = [A1|_], writeq(first_arg = A1), nl.
```